# Difference between "à quelle heure" and "pour quelle heure"

Tags: expressions

Is there a difference between these two phrases:

> On part pour quelle heure ?

and

> On part à quelle heure ?

Can I use à instead of pour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual sentence is *On part **à** quelle heure ?*

If someone asks me *On part **pour** quelle heure ?* I might understand that it is not about the time we have to leave the place we are, but the time we have to be at another place. Assuming there is a train every hour and the station is 20 minutes away, *On part pour 8 h* would mean that we have to leave at worst at 7:40 but actually earlier so as not to miss it.